# partition an Array with offset

Tags: scala, clojure

in Clojure I can partition a vector with offset step like

```
(partition 2 1 [1 2 3 4])
```

this returns a sequence of lists of n items each at offsets step apart.
for example the previous method returns

```
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4))
```

I just wonder how can I acheive the same in Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you need:

```
List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2,1).toList
```

Answer (score 2):

use `sliding` - `Array(1, 2, 3, 4).sliding(2)`. This would give you an `Iterator` and you can just call e.g. `toArray` and get `Array[Array[Int]]` where internals are as desired.

Answer (score 2):

There is function in the standard library `sliding` for this purpose

```
scala> val x = Array(1, 2, 3).sliding(2, 1)
x: Iterator[Array[Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> x.next
res8: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)

scala> x.next
res9: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> l.sliding(2).toList
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4), List(4, 5))
```